# Dropbox over Tor Browser

Tags: dropbox, tor

I have googled for that but found no tutorial.

Dropbox is blocked on my network. I can use Tor Browser to access blocked sites. Is it possible to use Tor Browser's proxy for Dropbox client to access internet?

Comment: If Dropbox is blocked on your network, you should observe the policy. You can also ask if it can be unblocked, or if a different sync application can be used such as Google Drive, OneDrive, Box, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to set the proxy for dropbox to the tor socks5 proxy of 127.0.0.1 and port 9050.

Having said that, tor isn't designed for large file transfers and would be frowned upon if it did work.

Comment: Thanks. I saw at home that Dropbox client has proxy settings. But when I install it on the PC I need proxy, it just shows a message that I'm offline. There's no button to open settings and set proxy. It's kinda troubling, require that I have Dropbox server access to only then allow me to set proxy to be able to access Dropbox server... I'll try Registry.

Answer (score 1):

Tor Browser runs its own copy of Tor which listens for SOCKS requests on the non-standard port 9150. So the SOCKS5 proxy server in Dropbox must be set to 127.0.0.1:9150.

If you want to use Dropbox when Tor Browser is not running then install the Tor Expert Bundle and set the SOCKS5 proxy server in Dropbox to 127.0.0.1:9050.